# Display an Announcement List from another SharePoint 2013 site within site collection

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have seen several examples of how to do this in SharePoint Designer 2010. I have been able to save my list to a site gallery. It will work when I add the web part to the same site however when I try to add to another site in the same site collection I get this error:

> List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

I also tried the Content Query Web Parts. It works but displays HTML with the Multi Line text.

Answer (score 0):

I think the CQWP should do the job, and you can specify your own XSLT to render the contents as you want.

Other option more "2013 wave" is to use the new Content By Search Webpart, configure the query to the specific list, and use the new Display templates (html + javascript) to render the content.

Not completely sure, but the error you're getting is expected, as the list view webpart is expecting the List in the same Site.